# Expected identifier before token in function pointer

Tags: c, function, structure, function-pointers, void-pointers

```
typedef enum
{
    TCP = 1,
    UDP
}protocol;

typedef enum
{
    DLL_Operation = 1,
    MT_Operation,
    Fork_Operation,
    IPC_Operation
}msgc;

struct f
{
    int seqNo;
    protocol p;
    msgc m;
    protocol q;
    int PayLoadSize;
    void (*payload_ptr)();
};
```

This is my structure which i am using...

Now i am assigning address of function in that function pointer defining in strucutre...

```
if(f2.m == 1)
{                                                                           
    f2.(*payload_ptr) = DLL;
    f2.payload_ptr();
}
else if(f2.m == 2)
{
    f2.(*payload_ptr) = MT; 
    f2.payload_ptr();       
}
else if(f2.m == 3)
{
    f2.(*payload_ptr) = Fork;   
    f2.payload_ptr();
}
else
{
    f2.(*payload_ptr) = IPC;        
    f2.payload_ptr();
}
```

in compiling this program... it is showing error like..

**error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token**

**f2.(*payload_ptr) = DLL;**

& same for all condition.... what is the solution..

this DLL, MT all are some function which i define for certain operation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the values to function pointers wrongly.

It should be like below for all the cases

```
if(f2.m == 1)
{                                                                           
    f2.payload_ptr = DLL;
    f2.payload_ptr();
}
```

Please ensure that functions like DLL are of type `void DLL();`